# adding variable to SSIS data flow sql command

Tags: sql-server, ssis, db2

I have an SSIS package with a data flow task which connects to an AS400 using the 'IBM DB2 UDB for iSeries IBMDASQL OLE DB provider'.

In an OLE DB Source my sql command has the following Where clause which works fine but I want to add a variable for the number of days of data to retrieve.

```
WHERE     (days(CURRENT DATE) - days(IMDATA02.IMDHP.DHDODT) <= 14)
```

I want to add a variable for the '14' value as I have multiple data flow tasks which use this same command and every time I need to change the value I am updating every data flow.

When I add a variable with datatype Int32 and a value of 14 and then change the where command to be the following and point Parameter0 at the user variable I get an error 'SQL0313 Number of host variables not valid'

```
WHERE     (days(CURRENT DATE) - days(IMDATA02.IMDHP.DHDODT) <= ?)
```

Is it possible to add a variable like I am trying to?

Comment: I've seen this issue before with db2; try setting ValidateExternalMetadata property on the OLE DB Source to False

Comment: @Jayvee no luck.  tried that and the error is the same

Comment: this is definitely a db2 oledb driver issue since with sql server what you describe works without problem. this might help : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/09226007-4786-4e78-b40c-7790e89ca6e7/oledb-data-source-parameters?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: @infiniteRefactor thanks for that.  That has fixed it.  Needed the parameter name in the mappings to be ""00001"".  The preview button still errors but the task works perfectly with the variable.